# Kotlin-Android - Alarm Manager not honoring set days for scheduling a service on specific day

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

In my app, I am letting the user select some days out of the week and they will also set a time. Something similar to alarm clock, except in this case, I will be starting a service on the specified day and time.

With the below code, my broadcast receiver is getting called, but it's getting called even on the days not selected by the user.

```
val startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

for (dayNum in selectedDays.values) {
    var intent = Intent(activity, DeviceLocationSharingStarter::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("startTime", true)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, dayNum, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    startCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15)
    startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40)
    startCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayNum)

    if(startCalendar.timeInMillis < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        startCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1)
    }

    var alarmManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startCalendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent)
}
```

My selected days is a Collection and it has values like ("Monday" to 2, "Friday" to 6), but it's Tuesday today and while testing my broadcast receiver was called at the time specified.

How do I fix this to only get fired during the days specified in selectedDays collection?

Edit - I even tried setting intervalMillis in setRepeating function to "7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000" and also to "24 * 60 * 60 * 1000", still the broadcast receiver gets called on the days not set.

Comment: have you ever tried setExact over alarm manager?

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu - Will give it a try and let you know. I feel it's more based on the interval millis that we are passing. And am not sure when it considers the day that we set, since we pass calendar.timeInMillis as the param.

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu - Seems like setExact doesn't repeat the alarm, so might not work in my case. I need something that repeats the alarm. I feel that either something is wrong with the way am setting intent or with the interval.